# bootstrap-4 height 100 with overflowing content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is another bootstrap h-100 question but it adds some complexity.

Goal is to have a bootstrap container with a background image which contains three columns. The left and middle cols have a background-color set and should always fit the height of the container. The middle col contains some text (which on smaller screen grows and exceeds the viewport height). All in all the container should fit the viewport height.

I created an example here: https://www.codeply.com/go/2iMM4dthOK

Currently I use `body{min-height: 100%}` which leads to good results with the laptop-viewport. But when you switch to the desktop-viewport you'll notice that the container doesn't fit the viewport. There's a solution for it called `body{height: 100%}`. Yes, solved! No, not yet. Switch back laptop-viewport and you'll see that now the container does not grow with the content of the middle col.

Any CSS magician out there that can help?

**Edit**
Obviously the viewport needs a certain height to observe the problem. I'm currently testing with desktop: 1440x780 and laptop: 1200x780 resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove h-100 from all div and add display:flex to row
add css equal to row as below

```
css:
.equal{
display:flex;
}   
html:
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row equal">
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-left">
                col1
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-middle">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.<br>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-right">
                col3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: like so https://www.codeply.com/go/EtfQ4Jaxmr ? Doesn't solve it for me. Result is the same like my `body{min-height: 100%}` example. And BTW the bootstrap .row already has `display: flex` set.